# CakePHP find returns results with missing fields

Tags: php, cakephp, find, cakephp-2.0

I need to get my `User` info and when I call

`$this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $user_id)));`

the result contains just some of the fields.

I've currently updated database schema. On dev server it runs fine and returns all fields but on the production server those new fields are missing. Those servers have exactly the same configuration.

I've already tried to remove contents of `app/tmp/cache/models` and I am using `File` engine for caching.

The `schema.php` file is up to date, the contents of files in `app/tmp/cache/models` indicate that those fields are present but I have not been able to retreive them on the production server. The only difference perhaps is database and debug level. I've tried copying the database and using it with the dev server and that worked well.

I cannot obviously set debug to 2 on the production server.

Did anyone of you experience any sort of similar behavior?

PS I am using Cake 2.3.3

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting cached results ? If you add new records, do you get them in the find ?

Comment: I would say Chris is correct. 

remove the contents of tmp/cache/models and you will be up and running again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer was actually pretty simple. I had to remove not just the contents of `app/tmp/models`, but what actually made it work was removing of the contents of  `app/tmp/persistent`.

Comment: You can also just turn debug on - this should force it to get fresh cache every time.

Comment: Yep, that would definitely solve it, but since it's a production server, this is not a possibility

Comment: It's just PHP - do a check for ?debug=1 and a valid IP - if so, set debug to 2 - otherwise 1...something like that.  If you're dealing with bank accounts or something, that's probably not a great idea, but for most sites, I think it's ideal, as you can more easily determine issues among other things.

Answer (score 3):

My answer differs from @Elwhis's slightly. I'm on **Cake 2.4.5**. For me there was no `app/tmp/models` directory or `app/tmp/persistent`. `models` and `persistent` were both under `app/tmp/cache`. Just like @Elwhis, looking in the `app/tmp/cache/models` directory showed the missing fields, so it was confusing.

**To fix**, I deleted all files from `app/tmp/cache/persistent`. Note that if you delete the directory itself, you'll get a 500 error from CakePHP.

I recommend adding the deletion of files in that directory to your deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

> **Elwhis**: The answer was actually pretty simple. I had to remove not just the contents of app/tmp/models, but what actually made it work was removing of the contents of  app/tmp/persistent.

This still works to CakePHP 3, it fixed my problem!

**Update 1**

There are a simple way to clean up the cache with Bake CLI Tool, following below:

[Cache Shell Command](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/cache.html)

To clear one cache config:

> bin/cake cache clear

To clear all cache configs:

> bin/cake cache clear_all

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).