# Preparing to go live with website - what to do or not?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have finally my project ready to go live, is there a check list of things to go through before uploading the files to the webserver?
Are there any Files or Folders to be deleted before going live.

Version of cake: 2.3.8

I found out to set the debug level to 0.
Set the cookie in core.php

Do I need to remove the following folders?

/app/Console

/lib/Cake/Test

/lib/Cake/TestSuite

Any other security advise please?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, these folders can be deleted and app/Config/Schema, but it's not neccessary

Comment: Thank you, anything else needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't deploy anything to production that isn't needed. If your project doesn't require those folders to function, then don't deploy them.

Make sure to check out the short [deployment guide from the cake docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html).

Also here's a more general [website launch checklist](http://lite.launchlist.net/).

Comment: Thanks Matt the website launch is nice one too :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making sure your deployment process resets caches appropriately. This can differ depending on how you have things set up, but by default CakePHP uses a file cache. Regardless, it can really hose you to let the cache linger when things should be updated like model schema, etc. For example, see [my answer to another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23002674/135101).